# I’m 16, I’m stuck outside of Australia with an expired Australian passport and my mother is refusing to give me my valid one. What can I do?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens

My parents are divorced and still in a custody battle over my sister and me so we need signatures from both of them for me to get a passport. We got a passport earlier this year but because my dad isn’t in Australia they couldn’t give it to him so they gave it to my mum. Now she’s refusing to give me my passport. I’ve got recordings of her saying she won’t give it to me. Is there anything I can do to get my passport so I can come back home? I do have an Afghan passport but my Aussie passport and afghan passport are under different names. What can I do? Please help. I want to go home.

Comment: Have you talked to the Australian consulate in the country where you currently are? As an Australian citizen, they should be able to give you advice and/or assistance relevant to your situation.

Comment: In most developed countries, people under 18 are considered minors, and are subject to their parent's control. In this case, it'd be up to your mum to control where you travel, and even whether or not to let you hold your passport. I agree, however, that speaking to the Australian consulate is a reasonable thing for you to do.

Comment: An ongoing custody battle means there is a court involved, with the power to issue orders to your parents. Have you tried contacting the court?

Comment: Adding to the comment by @PatriciaShanahan some family law courts appoint (or allow the appearance of) attorneys to represent the children in contentious divorce or custody cases. If there is an attorney representing you in the custody matter, you should speak to them.

Comment: What's the motiviation behind your mother's behavior? Does she not want you to come to Australia? If so, why ? The easiest way to solves this would be to reach an agreement with your mother. It's hard to give advice if we don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 5):

The 'easiest' solution would be if you can get your mother to agree getting the passport to you. Ask her, or have someone else ask for you. If she insist ask for the reasons why she doesn't want you to have the passport and travel to Australia. There might be problems on her side you do not know about.

The next thing, maybe while getting an answer from your mother, is contacting the Australian embassy or consulate.

If both those routes fail, the court where they fight the custody battle. You may be able to ask them for help.

Comment: An application for an [Emergency passport](https://www.passports.gov.au/getting-passport-how-it-works/special-travel-documents/emergency-passports) may also be possible. The emergency being: need to return and that an existing passport is not available due to the mothers refusal. Is the mother and passport in Australia?